# water spheres on a hot pan

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

Today accidently I poured a little bit of water on a very hot pan , and something weird happened , where the quantity of water split into smaller spheres that moved around fast in the pan. I'm wondering about the physics concept behind that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [Leidenfrost effect.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect) When water is sprinkled on the hot pan, the water surface immediately in contact with the hot pan vapourises. This vapour surface insulates the rest of the droplet from vapourising. Now a liquid droplet exists over vapour. The hot vapour has a lot of energy and moves around rapidly, the water droplet moves along with the vapour.

Comment: Interesting... thank you.  But why doesn't the water stay as one droplet moving around ,but instead is divided into few smaller droplets?